# Is the same memory address copied to the main function in this case?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am a beginner in programming in general, and I am concerned about memory allocation. In this function, I dynamically allocate memory for a string in a struct, and later pass this struct to an array.

I believe that both memory locations are the same, but I want to confirm with people that are more experienced than I am.

I free the memory if the user decides not to add the item, but as soon as it confirms, the struct is passed to the array and then it is later "destroyed" because of the way the stack works. However, if the memory addresses are different, i would have memory that is never freed, and I know this is not good.

```
void addShopItem(ShopItem *shoppingList, int shopListIndex)
{
  ShopItem ListItem;
  char itemName[MAXSTR];

  // Asking the user for input
  printf("Item %d: ", shopListIndex + 1);
  fgets(itemName, MAXSTR, stdin);
  itemName[strlen(itemName) - 1] = '\0';

  // Some code goes here

  ListItem.name = malloc(strlen(itemName) + 1);

  if (ListItem.name == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error. Memory not allocated");
    exit(1);
  }

  strcpy(ListItem.name, itemName);

  // This is the part that concerns me
  if (confirmItemToList(&ListItem) == false)
  {
    free(ListItem.name);
    return addShopItem(shoppingList, shopListIndex);
  }
  else
  {
    shoppingList[shopListIndex] = ListItem;
  }
  return;
}

// I was using this function to later free the memory in all the structs in the array
void freeMemoryAndReset(ShopItem *shoppingList)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < MAXITEMS && shoppingList[i].name != NULL)
  {
    free(shoppingList[i].name);
    shoppingList[i].amount = 0;
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a struct, it is passed by value, and thus copied. All of its members are copied as well. However, if one of those is a pointer, then the copied pointer still holds the same memory address.

```
+----------+
| struct A |          +-----------+
| char *s ----------->| "Hello"   |
+----------+          +-----------+
                       ^
                      /
+-----------+        /
| copy of A |       /
| char *s ----------  
+-----------+
```